# Trying to open webpages in a loop in chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome-devtools

Trying to open a series of webpages in a loop one after the other with some sleep in between in Chrome DevTools (on a USB connected Android device). Following is my snippet:

```
var canList = ['google.com', 'apple.com','facebook.com']

for(i=0;i<canList.length;i++)
{
    setTimeout(timeoutTrigger.bind(this, canList[i]), i*5000);
}

function timeoutTrigger(href) {
    console.log('Loading ' + href + '...' + Date.now())
    open('http://' + href, '_top')
}
```

It always loads the first one and then seems to stop and nothing happens after that. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1: you open the pages in `_top`, that means you update current tab to another page, the chrome dev tool get reloaded too, and your function stops running because it's gone. change to

```
open('http://' + href, '_blank')
```

to open it in new tab.

2:  open multiple pages in current page will get blocked by Chrome's popup blocking feature, so check the address bar to allow open multiple pages.

Comment: So what I finally aim to do is get some timing results for each page using `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]`. For that I need to open pages in the same tab. Is there some way to open pages in the same tab?

Comment: maybe use iframe?

Comment: iframes have the further problem that most websites will not allow to be loaded in the context of a frame and hence they won't be able to be loaded.